# Issues settings up subdomains w/ nginx

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I am trying to setup a subdomain for my website for PhpMyAdmin but I am having issues trying to get it to work. When I visit my website everything is working as intended, but when I visit my subdomain that I have setup it shows me the regular website and nothing related to PhpMyAdmin. I have been trying several different combinations to try and get this working but I can't figure this out. This is the first time of me trying to use nginx so I need some help. Here are my following configuration files.

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.cozykittygames.com;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}

server {
    server_name  pma.cozykittgames.com;
    root    /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
}
```

I have tried everything I could think of, my subdomain was setup as an exact copy of the regular domain just with the server_name being different. At this point if I can get the subdomain to point to the right folder would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a typo in your server name, leaving out the "y" in "kitty". It should be:

```
 server_name  pma.cozykittygames.com;
```

Comment: I didn't spot the typo directly, either. My first thought was to check the DNS, since you provided real domain names. I only noticed the typo once I ran `dig` on the `pma` subdomain and noticed it didn't resolve.